# PyOpenSSL: How to load every certificate from a certificate chain file?

Tags: python, ssl, pyopenssl

I'm trying to load all certificates from a certificate chain file, but
`crypto.load_certificate()`
seems to only load the first certificate.

I've tried `SSL.context.load_client_ca()`, but I couldn't access the certificates.

Do I have to split the certificates and read them one by one?